# Как заменить цикл for на метод forEach в данном коде?

Tags: javascript

Как заменить цикл for на метод forEach в данном коде?

```
var placeImage = document.getElementById('myModal');
var bigImage = document.getElementById("img");
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("foto-portfolio");


for( var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
  images [i].onclick= function(){
   placeImage.style.display = "block";
    bigImage.src = this.src;
  }
}

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

close.onclick = function() { 
  placeImage.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
images.forEach((image) => {
  image.onclick = function() {
    placeImage.style.display = "block";
    bigImage.src = this.src;
  }
});
```